# opening a modal form after another modal form - 2nd modal form doesnt show

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a c# net program that asks a question thru a modal form with yes or no.
Responding with yes will show another modal form to get input for name.
I have coded it this way.

```
if (count == 0)
{
 Form5 nameQstFrm = new Form5("Add Name?");
 DialogResult nameQstRst = nameQstFrm.ShowDialog(this);
 if (nameQstRst == DialogResult.Yes)
 {
   nameQstRst = DialogResult.None;
   this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
   string nameGet = "";
   Form6 nameAddFrm = new Form6("Name Please～");
   DialogResult nameAddRst = nameQstFrm.ShowDialog(this);
   if (nameAddRst == DialogResult.Yes)
   {
    nameAddRst = DialogResult.None;
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    nameGet = nameAddFrm.AddShitaStr;
    kyaranameKanaTxt = nameGet.Trim();
   }
   kyaranameAru = true;
 }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: so, what is a problem actually?

Answer (score 1):

Modify this line (i think is typo):

```
Form6 nameAddFrm = new Form6("Name Please");
DialogResult nameAddRst = nameQstFrm.ShowDialog(this);
```

to

```
Form6 nameAddFrm = new Form6("Name Please");
DialogResult nameAddRst = nameAddFrm.ShowDialog(this);
```

You cannot invoke `ShowDialog` twice on same instance.